# Xamarin.iOS Finger Paint on UI

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uikit

I want to draw with one finger on a UIImageView-Control with Xamarin iOS.
What I found: 
[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461819/draw-into-uiimage)
[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541038/finger-drawing-in-xamarin-ios-app-c)

This two examples won't work properly because with the first link there are the following problems:

1. I have to use two fingers for drawing, but I want to use only one Finger (don´t be confused with the pictures, I have to use two fingers to active the touch function)
2. The positioning is wrong I guess the problems relies on due to wrong scaling (see the attached pictures)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the code I currently have:

```
public partial class DetailImageView : UIImageView
{
    DetailImageViewController ctrl;
    public DetailImageView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

    }

    public void Initialize(DetailImageViewController rootController)
    {
        ctrl = rootController;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;

        drawOnTouch(touch);

        //DrawLineOnImage();
    }

    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;

        drawOnTouch(touch);

        //DrawLineOnImage();
    }


    private void drawOnTouch(object data)
    {

        UITouch touch = data as UITouch;

        if (null != touch)
        {

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(this.Image == null ? this.Frame.Size : this.Image.Size);

            //UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(this.Frame.Size);

            using (CoreGraphics.CGContext cont = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
            {

                if (this.Image != null)
                {

                    cont.TranslateCTM(0f, this.Image.Size.Height);
                    cont.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
                    cont.DrawImage(new RectangleF(0f, 0f, Convert.ToSingle(this.Image.Size.Width)
                                                  , Convert.ToSingle(this.Image.Size.Height)), this.Image.CGImage);
                    cont.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
                    cont.TranslateCTM(0f, -this.Image.Size.Height);


                } //end if

                CGPoint lastLocation = touch.PreviousLocationInView(this);
                CGPoint pt = touch.LocationInView(this);
                using (CGPath path = new CGPath())
                {

                    cont.SetLineCap(CGLineCap.Round);
                    cont.SetLineWidth(10);
                    cont.SetStrokeColor(0, 2, 3, 1);

                    var xMultiplier = Image.Size.Height / Frame.Height;
                    var yMultiplier = Image.Size.Width / Frame.Width;

                    var xLoc = lastLocation.X * xMultiplier;
                    var yLoc = lastLocation.Y * yMultiplier;

                    path.MoveToPoint(xLoc, yLoc);
                    path.AddLines(new CGPoint[] { new CGPoint(xLoc,
                                                              yLoc),
                        new CGPoint(pt.X * xMultiplier, pt.Y * yMultiplier) });
                    path.CloseSubpath();

                    cont.AddPath(path);
                    cont.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
                    this.Image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                }//end using path


            }//end using cont
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
            this.SetNeedsDisplay();

        }//end if
    }//end void drawOnTouch
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The positioning is wrong I guess the problems relies on due to wrong
>   scaling

Because when we use the image, the image's size is usually different from the `UIImageView`'s size. You use the image's size to draw paths, so it will miss its position. Try to modify like this:

```
if (null != touch)
{

    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(this.Frame.Size);

    using (CoreGraphics.CGContext cont = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
    {

        if (this.Image != null)
        {

            cont.TranslateCTM(0f, this.Frame.Size.Height);
            cont.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
            cont.DrawImage(new RectangleF(0f, 0f, Convert.ToSingle(this.Frame.Size.Width)
                                            , Convert.ToSingle(this.Frame.Size.Height)), this.Image.CGImage);
            cont.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
            cont.TranslateCTM(0f, -this.Frame.Size.Height);


        } //end if

        CGPoint lastLocation = touch.PreviousLocationInView(this);
        CGPoint pt = touch.LocationInView(this);
        using (CGPath path = new CGPath())
        {

            cont.SetLineCap(CGLineCap.Round);
            cont.SetLineWidth(10);
            cont.SetStrokeColor(0, 2, 3, 1);

            var xLoc = lastLocation.X;
            var yLoc = lastLocation.Y;

            path.MoveToPoint(xLoc, yLoc);
            path.AddLines(new CGPoint[] { new CGPoint(xLoc,
                                                    yLoc),
            new CGPoint(pt.X, pt.Y) });
            path.CloseSubpath();

            cont.AddPath(path);
            cont.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
            this.Image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        }//end using path


    }//end using cont
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    this.SetNeedsDisplay();

}//end if
```

About

> I have to use two fingers for drawing, but I want to use only one
>   Finger

What do you mean this? The code can be used drawing paths with only finger.

Comment: Thank you very much! Basically, it works now, but:
The image gets now scaled to the size of the frame, so the quality of the image is getting lower! How can I modify the code to draw on the original image and not on the shrunk one?
Regarding the second point: I have to use two fingers to draw e.g. a line, to draw only a point works when I tap on the screen with one finger but not when I´m moving the touch.